# Heroku Django Celery: NameError: name 'DATABASES' is not defined

Tags: django, heroku, django-celery, django-settings, kombu

I am following along [this](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django) tutorial to get celery and django running on heroku.

However, I get this error in my logs when I put in the specified code for the worker:

```
2011-12-22T05:31:56+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `python canada/manage.py run_gunicorn -b "0.0.0.0:47336" -w 3`
2011-12-22T05:31:56+00:00 app[web.1]: Unexpected error: (<type 'exceptions.NameError'>, NameError("name 'DATABASES' is not defined",), <traceback object at 0x11a9560>)
2011-12-22T05:31:56+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2011-12-22T05:31:56+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "canada/manage.py", line 11, in <module>
2011-12-22T05:31:56+00:00 app[web.1]:     import settings
2011-12-22T05:31:56+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/canada/settings.py", line 51, in <module>
2011-12-22T05:31:56+00:00 app[web.1]:     CELERY_RESULT_DBURI = DATABASES['default']
2011-12-22T05:31:56+00:00 app[web.1]: NameError: name 'DATABASES' is not defined
2011-12-22T05:31:57+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation finished
2011-12-22T05:31:57+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2011-12-22T05:31:58+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited
```

My settings.py looks like

```
import djcelery

djcelery.setup_loader()

BROKER_BACKEND = "djkombu.transport.DatabaseTransport"
CELERY_RESULT_DBURI = DATABASES['default']
...
```

When I synced before adding this line, `CELERY_RESULT_DBURI = DATABASES['default']`, it ran fine. According to [the document](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django#postgres_database_config)

> When you deploy a Django application, the compile process appends the following code to your settings.py to use the DATABASE_URL environment variable:

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Heroku is adding `DATABASES` configuration at the end of your `settings.py`, so when you make reference to `DATABASES`in your settings.py, it doesn't exists.

You can replicate Heroku `DATABASES` settings in your own file (it just read from `DATABASE_URL` from env, see : [django-heroku-template](https://github.com/cyberdelia/django-heroku-template/blob/master/project_name/settings.py)) or use your own [buildpack](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python/blob/master/bin/compile).

Comment: Thats exactly what I wanted. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this before run your app:

```
export DATABASE_URL='postgres://postuser:postpassword@posthost/dbname'
```

Using the environment variables is the easiest way to Heroku to automatically set database credentials, without modifying settings.py

Comment: Do you mean do `heroku run export DATABASE_URL='postgres://postuser:postpassword@posthost/dbname'` and then restart my app? And I would have to put in all my database info? if Heroku is supposed to append this to my settings.py why isn't it working, since I followed along the tutorial?